# Параллельный запуск Selenium тестов через pytest в различных браузерах

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

Есть UI тесты на фреймворке pytest, есть Selenium grid с несколькими браузерами.
Задача: запустить параллельный прогон тестов в двух браузерах. Браузеры на разных хостах, поэтому последовательный запуск не вариант.

test.py:

```
class TestSuit:
    def test_1(self, app):
        app.do_smth()
        assert True

    def test_2(self, app):
        app.do_smth()
        assert True
```

application.py:

```
class Application:
    def __init__(self, browser_name):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://host:port/wd/hub,
            desired_capabilities={'browserName': browser_name}
        )
```

conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize(
        'browser_name',
        metafunc.config.getoption('browser').split(';'),
        scope='session'
    )

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app(browser_name):
    return Application(browser_name)
```

Запускаю так:

```
py.test test.py --browser "internet explorer;chrome"
```

В итоге сначала тесты проходят на одном браузере, потом на втором. Т.е. один из хостов простаивает.
Пробовал xdist с опцией -n 2, тогда два теста параллельно запускаются на IE, а потом два параллельно на Chrome. Т.е. опять один хост простаивает.

Как сделать, чтобы параллельно запустились оба браузера и в них прогонялись тесты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать через хуки самого xdist, но это надо углубляться в его внутренности, что сделать возможности раньше не предоставлялось (надеюсь доберусь).
Поэтому проще всего реализовать через xdist scheduler вида loadscope (разделяет тесты на разные воркеры по pytest scope):

application.py

```
import pytest


class Application:
    def __init__(self, browser_name):
        self.browser = browser_name

    def do_smth(self):
        pass
```

my_test.py (не следует использовать имя test.py иначе import test вызовет импорт из site-packages)

```
class TestSuit:
    def test_1(self, app):
        app.do_smth()
        assert True

    def test_2(self, app):
        app.do_smth()
        assert True
```

test_ie.py

```
import application
import pytest
from my_test import TestSuit


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    return application.Application('internet_explorer')
```

test_chrome.py

```
import application
import pytest
from my_test import TestSuit


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app():
    return application.Application('chrome')
```

И вызов через

```
pytest test_chrome.py test_ie.py -vv -s -n2 --dist loadscope
```

Собственно параллелизация может быть выставлена более чем 2, но все равно будет использовано только два первых воркера

Пример вывода

```
parallel_pytest$ pytest test_chrome.py test_ie.py -vv -s -n2 --dist loadscope
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- /home/asanko/venv_parallel_pytest/bin/python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /media/sf_Ubuntu-01/dev/parallel_pytest, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.20.1, forked-0.2
[gw0] linux2 Python 2.7.12 cwd: /media/sf_Ubuntu-01/dev/parallel_pytest
[gw1] linux2 Python 2.7.12 cwd: /media/sf_Ubuntu-01/dev/parallel_pytest
[gw0] Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56)  -- [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
[gw1] Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56)  -- [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
gw0 [4] / gw1 [4]
scheduling tests via LoadScopeScheduling

test_ie.py::TestSuit::test_1 <- my_test.py 
test_chrome.py::TestSuit::test_1 <- my_test.py 
[gw0] [ 25%] PASSED test_chrome.py::TestSuit::test_1 <- my_test.py 
[gw1] [ 50%] PASSED test_ie.py::TestSuit::test_1 <- my_test.py 
test_chrome.py::TestSuit::test_2 <- my_test.py 
[gw0] [ 75%] PASSED test_chrome.py::TestSuit::test_2 <- my_test.py 
test_ie.py::TestSuit::test_2 <- my_test.py 
[gw1] [100%] PASSED test_ie.py::TestSuit::test_2 <- my_test.py
```

Можно легко проверить, что все работает ожидаемо:

my_test.py

```
class TestSuit:
    def test_1(self, app, worker_id):
        with open('output', 'a') as f:
            f.write('test1/' + app.browser + '/' + worker_id + '\n')
        app.do_smth()
        assert True

    def test_2(self, app, worker_id):
        with open('output', 'a') as f:
            f.write('test2/' + app.browser + '/' + worker_id + '\n')
        app.do_smth()
        assert True
```

И заглядываем в итоговый файл output:

```
test1/internet_explorer/gw1
test1/chrome/gw0
test2/internet_explorer/gw1
test2/chrome/gw0
```

Собственно использование двух разных файлов с переопределенной фикстурой app позволяет создать два разные scope, которые распределяются по разным воркерам.

ADDED:

Также если фикстура app делает что-то сложнее, чем просто создание instance класса Application, то это можно вынести в фикстуру в тот же conftest.py, которая будет возвращать генератор фикстуры:

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app_prepare():
    def get_app_fixture(browser_name):
        # do_some_magic
        # for example add "!"
        return browser_name + "!"
    return get_app_fixture
```

test_ie.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app(app_prepare):
    browser_name = app_prepare('internet_explorer')
    return application.Application(browser_name)
```

test_chrome.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def app(app_prepare):
    browser_name = app_prepare('chrome')
    return application.Application(browser_name)
```

Comment: Тоже обратил внимание на `--dist=loadscope`, но не знал как прикрутить.. Спасибо! Поддерживать, конечно, не очень удобно будет. При добавлении новых тестов нужно будет в обертках для каждого браузера импортировать их.. Но это уже что-то рабочее, спасибо!

Comment: Стейтмент `from my_test import *` вместо `from my_test import TestSuit` тоже будет работать. Так что необходимо будет добавлять импорты только при добавлении новых модулей с тестами. Опять-таки удобством разделения тестов в разные модули можно пожертвовать в пользу унификации.